# Cordova hello world app crashing

Tags: android, cordova

I am new in Android Development. I am working on cordova platform

I have created a sample hello world app and getting this error when i am trying to open it in genymotion. ALthough the app compile succesfully but when i run it in genymotion it just shows the prompt with text "Unfortunately "APP" has stopped."

The Error log shows.

```
01-12 08:16:04.867    2073-2073/com.technoserves.crudnew D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
    01-12 08:16:06.107    2073-2073/com.technoserves.crudnew W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/technoserves/crudnew/CordovaApp; (14)
    01-12 08:16:06.119    2073-2073/com.technoserves.crudnew W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/technoserves/crudnew/CordovaApp;' failed
    01-12 08:16:06.135    2073-2073/com.technoserves.crudnew D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    01-12 08:16:06.135    2073-2073/com.technoserves.crudnew W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6142908)
    01-12 08:16:06.155    2073-2073/com.technoserves.crudnew E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.technoserves.crudnew/com.technoserves.crudnew.CordovaApp}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.technoserves.crudnew.CordovaApp" on path: /data/app/com.technoserves.crudnew-1.apk
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.technoserves.crudnew.CordovaApp" on path: /data/app/com.technoserves.crudnew-1.apk
                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-12 08:16:22.399    2073-2073/com.technoserves.crudnew I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2073 SIG: 9
```

I have updated my cordova to resolve but still same error however a few days ago it was working fine and i have build some apps.

Comment: library is not correctly added in your application

Comment: How to do it i dont know will you guide please

Comment: are you using eclipse or android studio?

Comment: i am using android studion (BETA) 0.8.6

Comment: Did you ever resolve this ? I've also run into this :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download Cordova jar file from following link:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/cordova/cordova-1.8.1.jar.zip

after that extract the folder and put cordova-1.8.1 inside your libs folder of project in eclipse

And right click on your project--> properties and Select Android from left pane and scroll to bottom remove  the cordova library if added.

then clean and build your project.

Comment: I am working on html,css and javascript. Is it need of JAR file??? I have built apps before and didn`t used jar

Comment: library or jar both are the same thing