# Hello World App crashing in Cordova 6.4.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova6.4.0

I am new to Cordova and I can't get the Cordova "hello world" application to display on Android Emulator but I can run same app in browser successfully. Also I can run the app in online cloud emulators.

Cordova version : 6.4.0

NodeJs : 4.6.1

Ubuntu : 14.04 64Bit

**This is my android virtual device settings**

[image: This is my android virtual device settings]

**This is my stacktrace when trying to run the hello world app.**

> [ 11-08 08:45:27.115  3256: 3256 W/google-breakpad ]
>
> #### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.115  3256: 3256 W/google-breakpad ] Chrome build
>   fingerprint:
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.115  3256: 3256 W/google-breakpad ]
>   1.0.0
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.115  3256: 3256 W/google-breakpad ] 10000
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.115  3256: 3256 W/google-breakpad ]
>   3874b69a-4a70-400e-94db-0744eafe8cbf
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.115  3256: 3256 W/google-breakpad ]
>
> #### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.115  3256: 3256 F/libc     ] Fatal signal 6
>   (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3256 (m.example.hello)
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.115  1183: 1183 W/         ] debuggerd: handling
>   request: pid=3256 uid=10060 gid=10060 tid=3256
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.119  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>
> ---
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.119  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ] Build fingerprint:
>   'Android/sdk_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:7.0/NYC/3245079:userdebug/test-keys'
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.119  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ] Revision: '0'
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.119  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ] ABI: 'x86_64'
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.119  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ] pid: 3256, tid: 3256,
>   name: m.example.hello  >>> com.example.hello <<<
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.119  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ] signal 6 (SIGABRT), code
>   -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ] Abort message:
>   '[FATAL:gpu_info_collector_android.cc(193)] failed to create a pbuffer
>   surface for fetching driver strings. EGL_SUCCESS (3000) '
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       rax 0000000000000000  rbx 00007ffef7ff9be8  rcx ffffffffffffffff  rdx 0000000000000006
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       rsi 0000000000000cb8  rdi 0000000000000cb8
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       r8  0000000000000305  r9  00007ffee3659c75  r10 0000000000000008  r11 0000000000000206
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       r12 0000000000000cb8  r13 0000000000000006  r14 00007ffef69eb000  r15 00007fff5da2f320
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       cs  0000000000000033  ss  000000000000002b
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       rip 00007ffef6984b27  rbp 0000000000000058  rsp 00007fff5da2ec88  eflags 0000000000000206
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>
> backtrace:
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       #00 pc 000000000008db27  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+7)
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       #01 pc 000000000008a5c1  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+65)
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       #02 pc 0000000000030241  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+17)
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       #03 pc 000000000002877d  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+77)
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.120  3275: 3275 F/DEBUG    ]
>       #04 pc 0000000002a93c38  /system/app/webview/webview.apk (offset 0x3c9c000)
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.415  1571: 1643 I/BootReceiver ] Copying
>   /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.419  1183: 1183 W/         ] debuggerd: resuming
>   target 3256
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.503  1233: 1233 I/Zygote   ] Process 3256 exited due
>   to signal (6)
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.629  1571: 3280 W/ActivityManager ]   Force finishing
>   activity com.example.hello/.MainActivity
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.631  1571: 3280 W/ActivityManager ] Exception thrown
>   during pause android.os.DeadObjectException   at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)  at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)  at
>   android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:784)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1128)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3483)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3319)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1821)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleAppCrashLocked(AppErrors.java:619)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.AppErrors.makeAppCrashingLocked(AppErrors.java:481)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:357)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:309)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:13226)
>     at
>   com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.631  1226: 1226 E/lowmemorykiller ] Error opening
>   /proc/3256/oom_score_adj; errno=2
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.751  1228: 1228 D/gralloc  ] Registering a buffer in
>   the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.751  1228: 1228 E/libEGL   ] called unimplemented
>   OpenGL ES API
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.751  1228: 1228 E/SurfaceFlinger ]
>   glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1200695526
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.751  1228: 1228 E/SurfaceFlinger ] got
>   GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.751  1571: 3280 W/WindowManager ] Screenshot failure
>   taking screenshot for (1440x2560) to layer 22015
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.753  1571: 1611 W/art      ] Long monitor contention
>   with owner NativeCrashReport (3280) at void
>   com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord,
>   android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo)(AppErrors.java:328)
>   waiters=4 in void
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient.binderDied()
>   for 249ms
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.753  1571: 1611 I/ActivityManager ] Process
>   com.example.hello (pid 3256) has died
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.755  1571: 1647 W/art      ] Long monitor contention
>   with owner NativeCrashReport (3280) at void
>   com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord,
>   android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo)(AppErrors.java:328)
>   waiters=6 in void
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$LocalService.notifyAppTransitionFinished()
>   for 126ms
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:27.763  1571: 1931 W/InputMethodManagerService ] Window
>   already focused, ignoring focus gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@17014ac
>   attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@52c4ec5
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:28.075  1571: 2551 W/art      ] Long monitor contention
>   with owner android.display (1647) at void
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(long)(WindowAnimator.java:138)
>   waiters=1 in void
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.finishDrawingWindow(com.android.server.wm.Session,
>   android.view.IWindow) for 132ms
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:28.205  1571: 1647 I/WindowManager ] Destroying surface
>   Surface(name=Starting com.example.hello) called by
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478
>   com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:365
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565
>   com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:427
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateAppWindowsLocked:196
>
> [ 11-08 08:45:30.183  1571: 1869 E/TaskPersister ] File error
>   accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
>
> Also these did not help.
>
> [Cordova hello world app crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897900/cordova-hello-world-app-crashing)
>
> [Cordova "hello world" app won't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149970/cordova-hello-world-app-wont-display)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed `CPU/ABI` from **Intel Atom (x86_64)** to **Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)**. It did work.